# Identify group given by explicit representations of its generators

Tags: group-theory, gap

I come to a situation that I have the explicit $3 \times 3$ real matrix representations of all generators and can prove that they
span a finite group. But I don't know the name of this group and its overall structures. Is there any simple way or sample
GAP code that I can use for this purpose? I'm a total new comer to GAP which seems to be the right tool that I need.

Thanks!

Shao-Feng

Comment: If the entries are integers, then everything is easy. If there are also square roots, then GAP's efficiency is heavily dependent on the LCM of the square-free parts of the square roots. If there are more general real numbers, then you may find GAP more difficult to use for this. If you give the generators (and they are reasonable), I can show you the GAP code to enter them.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this question from the unanswered queue, just a simple example of a calculation in GAP which you may have in mind. Here we are dealing with the irreducible representation of $A_5$ of degree 3:

```
gap> gens:=
> [ [ [                             -1,   0,                    E(5)+E(5)^4 ], 
>     [                              0,   1,                              1 ], 
>     [                   -E(5)-E(5)^4,   0,                   -E(5)-E(5)^4 ] 
>   ], 
>   [ [                              0,   0,                             -1 ], 
>     [ -2*E(5)-E(5)^2-E(5)^3-2*E(5)^4,   1, -2*E(5)-E(5)^2-E(5)^3-2*E(5)^4 ], 
>     [                    E(5)+E(5)^4, - 1,                             -1 ] ] 
> ];;
gap> G:=Group(gens);;
gap> Size(G);
60
gap> StructureDescription(G);
"A5"
```

**Remark**: GAP ignores whitespace symbols in the input, so the matrices are formatted this way just for easy reading.

Comment: And [here you may find another example](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1124367), thanks to @ahulpke