# Finding all the group elements of a certain order of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Consider a group $G=\langle P, Z, Q \rangle$ generated $P,Z,Q$ where 
$$Z=\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
    -1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -1\\
  \end{array} } \right] $$ $$ \quad P = \frac{1}{2} \left [ {\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & \tau^{-1} & -\tau\\
    \tau^{-1} & \tau & 1\\
    \tau & -1 & \tau^{-1}\\
  \end{array} } \right]$$
  where $\tau=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$
and $$Q=\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \rho ^2\\
    0 & -\rho & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]$$ where $\rho = e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ is a third root of unity,

**I want to understand the elements of $G$ that are of order $3$. Is there any known algorithm to find such elements?**

I have shown that the center of $G$ is $SL_3(\mathbb{C})\cap \mathbb{C}^*.Id = C_3$, i.e. the scalar matrices where the scalars are third roots of unity. So I would like to know which elements not in the center are of order 3.

I know the following about $G$, in case it might be useful:

> The order of $G$ is $1080$ and $G$ is a $3:1$ central extension of the alternating group $A_6.$ That is following sequence is exact. $$0 \to C_3 \to G \to A_6 \to 0.$$

Since I don't know much about the group structure of $G,$ I am having hard time to answer the question above. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well there are either 22 or 242.

Comment: 22 if $G$ contains an element of order 9, and 242 if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group is (by explicit computation in GAP) the (unique) perfect group of order 1080. Its elements of order 3 are the elements in the centre, C3, as well as two conjugacy classes of order 120 each (they consist of elements that in the A_6 image are 3-cycles, respectively double 3-cycles). Representatives of these two classes are given by $PZ$ and $PQP$. A nice matrix representative for one of the classes is the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
\end{array}\right),$$
but the other class has only more messy representatives.

In case anyone is interested in the calculation itself, I defined the group:

```
z:=[[-1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,-1]];
tau:=(1+ER(5))/2;
p:=1/2*[[1,tau^-1,-tau],[tau^-1,tau,1],[tau,-1,tau^-1]];
rho:=E(3);
q:=[[1,0,0],[0,0,rho^2],[0,-rho,0]];
G:=Group(z,p,q);
```

and determined classes whose representatives have order 3:

```
cl:=ConjugacyClasses(G);;
cl:=Filtered(cl,x->Order(Representative(x))=3);;
List(cl,Size);
[ 1, 1, 120, 120 ]
```

Concerning the question for elements of order 9:

```
s:=SylowSubgroup(G,3);;
AbelianInvariants(s);
[ 3, 3 ]
Exponent(s);
3
```

tells us that the 3-Sylow subgroup is the nonabelian group of order 27 and exponent 3.

To find diagonal matrices I would look at the stabilizer of the three 1-dimensional subspaces spanned by the standard basis vectors:

```
s:=Stabilizer(G,[1,0,0],OnLines);
s:=Stabilizer(s,[0,1,0],OnLines);
s:=Stabilizer(s,[0,0,1],OnLines);
```

and you get the subgroup generated by the diagonal matrices for [1,-1,-1] and E(3)*[-1,-1,1]. You could ask for `Elements(s)` to get a list.

Comment: @ahulpke: some explanation on how you arrived at two representatives would be helpful to me, because I do not know anything about GAP yet. Thanks!

Comment: @monomorphic: I added a brief description of the commands used.

Comment: Questions: 1) How does one read the statement $[1,1,120,120]?$ 2) Is the question about order $9$ related to my original question? Or were you answering for the earlier comments?

Comment: Oh I get the comment: If $G$ does not contain an element of order $9,$ then there are $1+1+120+120 = 242$ elements of order $3$. Correct? But I don't get how you showed that  there are no elements of order $9$.

Comment: @monomorphic: Elements of order $9$, if they exist, would belong to the Sylow $3$-subgroup, but the latter has exponent $3$, so the order of any its non-trivial element is $3$.

Comment: @ahulpke: How did you conclude that $ PZ$ and $PQP$ are the representatives of the conjugacy classes? Is this also known somehow from GAP?

Comment: @monomorphic: By using the command `Factorization(G,elm);` with `elm` being the group element. I tried all elements of order 3 and picked shortest ones.

Comment: Hi! I want to ask a question, if I may: is it possible to find all the diagonal matrices in the group $G$? Other than $C_3$ of course? Could you add this to your answer if possible?

Comment: @monomorphic I added a description

Comment: Thanks a lot! What does $E(3)^*$ mean?

Comment: E(3) is GAP's way of representing a 3rd root of unity.